# How to replace excel as input data for automation

Tags: excel, automation, test-framework

I am working on an automation framework which requires me to validate the xml structure and value.
for ex.

Testcase: xyz
xml: `<<Doc>/<firsttag>/<secondtag>`
Value in the tag: 10

I'll pass the testcase, xml and the value in the excel. The output xml is validated against the xml and value provided in the excel. For each test case I'll have many xml and value.

Question is I want to remove excel input as there are machines without excel installed.
need a way handle input data other that excel.

Technology used here is JAVA.

Comment: The xml syntax of the testcase seems to be not okay. Could you provide a valid testcase?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: provide the testcase input as a .txt text file:

```
1st line: tescase name
2nd line: value
3rd and all the following lines: xml
```

Your example:

```
xyz
10
<<Doc>/<firsttag>/<secondtag>
```

*(Side note: your XML syntax is broken)*